# Downloadable docx file on button click

Tags: python, django

I have files(docx file) which I need to let users download by clicking on a button.
These files were uploaded to a Model FileField.
This is my views.py

```
def files_view(request):
    files = FileModel.objects.filter(user=request.user)
    return render(request, template_name='folder/files_list.html')
```

and this is my template.html

```
{% for serving_files in user.files.all %}
<a href="{{ serving_files.url }}"><button>Download</button></a>
```

I'm doing this but the files are unable to download. What changes do I need to make?

Comment: Have you tried `download` attribute in your anchor tag?  `<a href="{{ serving_files.url }}" download><button>Download</button></a>`

Comment: @ans2human yes, tried. Didn't help either.

Comment: @ans2human I think as these are docx file which are not supported by browsers, I need to return them with HttpResponse. I'm just lost how can I make it return only when the button is clicked.

Comment: yes you will need to write a custom function that helps convert this file into `httprespose` and return it, let me provide you with an example.

Comment: Where are you storing the files? locally `media-root` or elsewhere?

Comment: @ans2human media root

Answer (score 0):

So onclick of button call this function, the code is untested but with minor tweaks this should work.

```
import os
from django.conf import settings
from django.http import HttpResponse, Http404

def download(request, path):
    file_path = os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, path)
    if os.path.exists(file_path):
        with open(file_path, 'rb') as fh:
            response = HttpResponse(fh.read(), content_type='application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document')
            response['Content-Disposition'] = 'inline; filename=' + os.path.basename(file_path)
            return response
    raise Http404
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried something like this too earlier reading from documentation but had questions with it. Do I need to put this in the same view I'm calling for template? And the files from model is exactly uploading to a folder in media root named ```word_documents``` and I've not made any changes to urls.py as there's no example working with ```path``` instead of something like this ```url(^'word_documents/<path>$')``` which I guess is updated as ```path```. Maybe?

Comment: And this alone gives me ```download() missing 1 required positional argument: 'path'
```

Answer (score 0):

I tweaked the code from @ans2human, and this worked for me in firefox and chrome:

```
def download_viewing_agreement_view(request):
    file_path = pathlib.Path(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, 'filename.docx')
    if os.path.exists(file_path):
        with open(file_path, 'rb') as fh:
            response = HttpResponse(fh.read(), content_type='application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document')
            filename = 'filename.docx'
            file_expr = "filename*=utf-8''{}".format(quote(filename))   # Handle a non-ASCII filename
            response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; {}'.format(file_expr)
            return response
```